# How to rewrite SQL for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlcode

I'm trying to rewrite two pieces of SQL Server code to PostgreSQL.

The 1st one is:

```
WHERE
    (DATEADD(S, Submit_Date, '1970-01-01')) >= DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE())
    OR
    (DATEADD(S, Last_Changed_Date, '1970-01-01')) >= DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE())
```

I keep getting an error regarding the S after the `DATEADD`.

The 2nd one is this:

```
WHERE (dbo.Test.[Log] LIKE '%%Status: Closed%%')
GROUP BY dbo.PYR.ID_Number
```

I need help for the mentioned SQL Server code lines to be modified for PostreSQL.

Any suggestions how they should be?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/dateadd should help you solve the first issue

Comment: For number 2, postgre doesn't use []-brackets

Comment: `where to_timestamp(submit_date) >= current_date - interval '3 days' or to_timestamp(last_changed_date) >= current_date - interval '3 days'`

Comment: `where test."Log" ~* 'Status: Closed'
group by pyr.id_number`

Comment: Only tag the rdbms you want your solution in, and provide a [mre] to explain what the query should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE
('1970-01-01'::timestamp + interval '1 second' * submit_date)  >= now()+interval '-3 days'
OR
('1970-01-01'::timestamp + interval '1 second' * Last_Changed_date)  >= now()+interval '-3 days'

WHERE  (dbo.Test."Log" ILIKE '%%Status: Closed%%')
GROUP BY dbo.PYR.ID_Number
```

Answer (score 0):

If `submit_date` and `Last_Changed_date` each have indexes, then the following is likely to perform better than the original first query:

```
WHERE submit_date >= extract(epoch FROM now() - interval '3 days')
   OR Last_Changed_date >= now() - interval '3 days')
```

Avoid operations on columns in the `WHERE` clause so that the condition will be *sargable* (***S**earch **ARG**ument **ABLE***); i.e., the database engine is able to scan an index when one is available instead if sequentially reading the whole table.

I chose to use `- interval '3 days'` instead of `+ interval '-3 days'` for readability. Subtracting an interval rather than adding a negative interval imposes less cognitive load on the reader, especially when the `-` is buried in a string somewhat distance from the `+`.

The second query can be rewritten as follows:

```
WHERE Test."Log" ILIKE '%%Status: Closed%%'
GROUP BY dbo.PYR.ID_Number
```

While `dbo.Test."Log"` also works as the column reference, it is better to only include the schema in the table reference in the `FROM` clause since this minimizes the number of changes that have to be made to the query if the schema changes.

If this is a frequent query condition and it's a large table, then explore options to index `Test."Log"`.